# Vb.net get keyboard layout

Tags: vb.net, layout, keyboard, dvorak

I'm currently learning the DVORAK layout on my QWERTY keyboard, which means that when I want to use keyboard shortcuts, such as Ctrl + C, in DVORAK that ends up being Ctrl + J, the convenience is lost when I have to use two hands to hit various commands. Windows does not appear to have a way to change the shortcuts, and autohotkey scripts do not work when you switch back to QWERTY, they instead ruin shortcut functionality for QWERTY until you exit the script.

So what I want to do is make my own program that will detect your layout and send the right keys, but first I need to detect which keyboard layout the user is using, and I can't seem to figure out how.

Is there a way to easily determine which keyboard layout someone is using?

Comment: Have you seen this API function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296(v=vs.85).aspx ?  Here's an example of using it in VB.NET: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeyboardlayout  I'm not sure, though, if that will work for detecting DVORAK vs. QWERTY.

Comment: It's a little over my head it seems, I'm not really sure what the parameter is supposed to be, or what to do with the string of numbers I get back from the VB function. If you know, could you explain how it works?

EDIT: I can get my input language using: InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage()
However, this gives no hint as to what the keyboard layout is.

Comment: I really don't know.  Does the return value from the `GetKeyboardLayout` function change when you switch from DVORAK to QWERTY?  If so, what changes, the high-word, the low-word, or both?

Comment: I somehow stumbled upon a method that works, even though I tried that earlier. I guess I'll only find the answer after asking for help :/


    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName.


Regular format returns "US".
Dvorak returns "United States-Dvorak".

Thank you for the help anyways!

Comment: Nice!  Now you can answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer :)  I'll vote it up.  I'm sure it will come in handy to others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon the right answer fortunately,

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName
```

Returns a string.

If your format is regular old QWERTY english, it returns "US"

If it's DVORAK(United-States) it returns "United States-Dvorak"